# Deleting a ListView item in React Native

Tags: listview, react-native, react-native-listview

I am having difficulty removing a row from a ListView. It removes the last element of the list, no matter which on is clicked. **However, console.log tells me that the array has correctly deleted the item, but it renders wrongly...** There are a few solutions already on the internet, but none have helped me solve my problem.

[GIF of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLSTf.gif)

**Logs**

As you can see, it actually does remove the right item, but displays the wrong array?

`Nov  6 22:18:39 Viviennes-Air reminders[25992] <Notice>: { rowID: '0' }
Nov  6 22:18:39 Viviennes-Air reminders[25992] <Notice>: [ 'testing 2', 'testing 3' ]
Nov  6 22:18:39 Viviennes-Air reminders[25992] <Notice>: { _rowHasChanged: [Function: rowHasChanged],
      _getRowData: [Function: defaultGetRowData],
      _sectionHeaderHasChanged: [Function],
      _getSectionHeaderData: [Function: defaultGetSectionHeaderData],
      _dataBlob: { s1: [ 'testing 2', 'testing 3' ] },
      _dirtyRows: [ [ false, false, true ] ],
      _dirtySections: [ false ],
      _cachedRowCount: 3,
      rowIdentities: [ [ '0', '1', '2' ] ],
      sectionIdentities: [ 's1' ] }`

Here's my constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);
const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
this.state = {
  items: [],
  dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows([]),
  newItem: "",
};}
```

The ListView:

```
<ListView
        style={styles.container}
        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
        enableEmptySections={true}
        renderRow={(data, sectionID, rowID) => this.renderRow(data, sectionID, rowID)}
        renderSeparator={(sectionId, rowId) => <View key={rowId} style={styles.separator}/>}
      />
```

The renderRow function:

```
renderRow(data, sectionID, rowID){
console.log("ITEM: ", data)
return <TouchableOpacity style={styles.listItem} onPress={() => this._delete({rowID})}
            activeOpacity={0.1}>
            <Text style={styles.listItemText}>{data}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>}
```

And finally, the delete function:

```
_delete(index){
  this.state.items.splice(index, 1)
  console.log(index)
  console.log(this.state.items)
  this.setState({
    dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(this.state.items)
  })
  console.log(this.state.dataSource)}
```

I have been trying to figure this our for 2 hours now, and I'm pretty sure I'm doing everything correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with Burak Karasoy, But there is another mistake in the code.

```
var newList= this.state.items.splice(index, 1)
```

newList will contain the deleted item, but actually what we need is new List after deleting the item.

So changes required to make your code work is,

Do not store `items` in state object. Instead store it as class instance variable and set the `dataSource`, like below code

```
this.items=this.getItems();
this.setState({
        dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(this.items)
 });
```

Now update your `_delete` method like below

```
_delete(index) {
    this.items.splice(index, 1)// This will remove the element at index, and update this.items with new array
    this.setState({
      dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(this.items)
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Solved my problem.